# Saving XlsxWriter workbook more than once

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, xlsxwriter

I am writing software that manipulates Excel sheets. So far, I've been using xlrd and xlwt to do so, and everything works pretty well.

- It opens a sheet (xlrd) and copies select columns to a new workbook (xlwt)
- It then opens the newly created workbook to read data (xlrd) and does some math and formatting with the data (which couldn't be done if the file isn't saved once) - (xlwt saves once again)

However, I am now willing to add charts in my documents, and this function is not supported by xlwt. I have found that xlsxwriter does, but this adds other complications to my code: xlsxwriter only has `xlsxwriter.close()`, which saves AND closes the document.

Does anyone know if there's any workaround for this? Whenever I use `xlsxwriter.close()`, my workbook object containing the document I'm writing isn't usable anymore.

Comment: You can't modify an existing excel file using xlsxwriter. You could read in your existing excel file using pandas.read_excel, if that's viable, and go from there using xlsxwriter.  Alternatively, openpyxl would probably be a better option for reading in an existing excel file and then modifying it.  You can make charts in openpyxl also ([link](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/charts/introduction.html)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fundamentally, there is no reason you need to read twice and save twice. For your *current* (no charts) process, you can just read the data you need using xlrd; then do **all** your processing; and write *once* with xlwt.

Following this workflow, it is a relatively simple matter to replace xlwt with XlsxWriter.